# YUI Library - Best way to keep global reference to object?

Tags: javascript, yui

I'm trying to use the yahoo ui history library. I don't see a great way to avoid wrapping all my function contents with the Y.use so that I can get access to the history object. I tried declaring it globally outside of the use() command, but this didn't seem to work. If you look at my showDashboard() and showReport1() methods, you can see I'm wrapping the contents, which seems redundant to have to do this for every function that uses the history. Is there a better way to do this?

All of the yahoo examples I've seen don't se functions at all and keep the entire sample inside a single use method.

```
 <div>
        <a href="#" onclick="showDashboard(); return false;">Dashboard</a> | 
        <a href="#" onclick="showReport1(); return false;">Report 1</a>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Global reference to Yahoo UI object
        var Y = YUI();       

        function showDashboard() {
            Y.use('*', function (Y) {
                var history = new Y.HistoryHash();
                history.addValue("report", "dashboard");
            });
        }

        function showReport1() {
            Y.use('*', function (Y) {
                var history = new Y.HistoryHash();
                history.addValue('report', "report1");  
                //var x = { 'report': 'report1', 'date': '11/12/2012' };
                //history.addValue("report", x);

            });
        }

        Y.use('history', 'tabview', function (Y) {
            var history = new Y.HistoryHash();
            var tabview = new Y.TabView({ srcNode: '#demo' });

            // Render the TabView widget to turn the static markup into an
            // interactive TabView.
            tabview.render();

            // Set the selected report to the bookmarked history state, or to
            // the first report if there's no bookmarked state.
            tabview.selectChild(history.get('report') || 0);

            // Store a new history state when the user selects a report.
            tabview.after('selectionChange', function (e) {
                // If the new tab index is greater than 0, set the "tab"
                // state value to the index. Otherwise, remove the "tab"
                // state value by setting it to null (this reverts to the
                // default state of selecting the first tab).
                history.addValue('report', e.newVal.get('index') || 0);
            });

            // Listen for history changes from back/forward navigation or
            // URL changes, and update the report selection when necessary.
            Y.on('history:change', function (e) {                
                // Ignore changes we make ourselves, since we don't need
                // to update the selection state for those. We're only
                // interested in outside changes, such as the ones generated
                // when the user clicks the browser's back or forward buttons.
                if (e.src === Y.HistoryHash.SRC_HASH) {
                    if (e.changed.report) {
                        // The new state contains a different report selection, so
                        // change the selected report.
                        tabview.selectChild(e.changed.report.newVal);
                    } else if (e.removed.report) {
                        // The report selection was removed in the new state, so
                        // select the first report by default.
                        tabview.selectChild(0);
                    }
                }

                if (e.changed.report) {
                    alert("New value: " + e.changed.report.newVal);
                    alert("Old value: " + e.changed.report.prevVal);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using plain function on click, attach handlers with YUI.
If you can change the HTML code - add id or class to the links, for example

```
<a id="btnShowDashboard" href="#">Dashboard</a>
```

Then in your use() add click handler to the buttons

```
Y.use('history', 'tabview', 'node', 'event', function (Y) {

  var bntShowDashboard = Y.one('#btnShowDashboard');
  if (bntShowDashboard) {
    bntShowDashboard.on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var history = new Y.HistoryHash();
      history.addValue("report", "dashboard");
    });
  }

...
})
```

That way you will be sure than on the moment of execution "history" is loaded.
BUT there is one drawback - until YUI modules are loaded, if you click the links nothing will happen.

Comment: Better still, declare var history = new Y.HistoryHash(); once inside the use() callback, then the click subscriber would only call history.addValue(...);

Comment: If you want to paint the UI before the YUI modules are loaded (understandable), you can either let button clicks do nothing or use the gallery-event-binder module to queue user events - http://yuilibrary.com/gallery/show/event-binder